# PHP Xpath - получить все, где содержится значение

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Есть запрос через xpath, который получает все элементы внутри родительского, где у элемента 'dsc' есть значение @

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$ftpUpload = $xml->xpath("/ftp/Upload[contains(@dsc, '@')]|/ftp/Download[contains(@dsc, '@')]");
```

Но здесь это сделано через перечисление конкретных веток через '|'
Можно ли без перечисления конкретных веток получить вообще все элементы, у которых у элемента 'dsc' есть значение @ ?

Т.е могут быть дочерние ветки(с любым уровнем вложенности), внутри родительских, которые будут выглядеть так:

```
$ftpUpload = $xml->xpath("/ftp/Upload/ftp[contains(@dsc, '@')]|/ftp/Download/ftp[contains(@dsc, '@')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

разобрался.
Вот так

```
$ftpUpload = $xml->xpath("//*[contains(@dsc, '@')]");
```